# Why the output of this C program is like this?

Tags: c

Why the output of the following program is

```
x = 10 y = 18
```

?

```
int y;
void fun(int x) {
 x+=2;
 y=x+2;
}

int main() {
 int x;
 x=10; y=11;
 fun(x);
 fun(y);
 printf("x=%d y=%d\n", x,y);
 return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't the output be 10 and 11 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `y` is a **global variable**, in the first call `fun(x);` `y` becomes `14` since `x` is `10`, `x += 2` makes `x == 12` and then `y = x + 2` which gives `14`. Then you call it with `y == 14`, which makes the local `x` in `fun()`, `x == 16` and then `y == y + 2` which is `18`.

Answer (score 2):

These are the states of variables before and after each of those function calls.

```
PRE: x=10, y=11
 fun(x);
POST: x=10, y=14
PRE: x=10, y=14
 fun(y);
POST: x=10, y=18
```

---

If you simply rename the local variable within fun() to something other than x, it becomes less complicated.

```
void fun(int x) {
  x+=2;
  y=x+2;
}
```

**can be rewritten as:**

```
void fun(int local_var) {
  y=local_var+4; //y is global, local_var is thrown away at the end of this scope.
}
```